# Eclipse Oxygen Java giving empty error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some Java that, in theory, draws a line from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the 500x500 window. The code:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class graphix extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new graphix();
    }

    public graphix(){

        this.setSize(500, 500);

        this.setTitle("Title Here");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.add(new Draw(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }


    private class Draw extends JComponent{

        public void paint(Graphics g){

            Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D)g;

            graph2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            Shape drawLine = new Line2D.Float(10, 10, 490, 490);

            graph2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

            graph2.draw(drawLine);

        }

    }

}
```

When i run this code, eclipse gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at graphix.graphix.main(graphix.java:11)
```

normally in eclipse, the error message will be displayed in the empty space between those two lines, but it says the error is triggered at line 11, which is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

My project name is graphix, and the class file name is graphix.java

**EDIT:**

There is also a non-fatal error:

```
The declared package "" does not match the expected package "graphix"
```

triggered by:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
```

Comment: I was able to run the code without any issue, I think you didnt save or build the file correctly, that's why its showing the wrong line number

Comment: I tried creating a completely new project, and copy/pasting the code, it gave me the same error. and pressing the little white-on-green play button builds it then runs it right?

Comment: Same, Eclipse Oxygen. Java 8, worked fine as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package declaration is missing on the top of the file, it must match the file structure inside your project:

```
package xxx.yyy.zzz;
```